# app.module.ts error with custom selector tag ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I work with ionic 4 and Angular 7.

I previously worked with Ionic3 and it seems that some things has chaanged too

I'm trying to implement a page using a custom selector tag `<app-side-menu></app-side-menu>` in the file app.component.html

I get the error

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'app-side-menu' is not a known
>   element:
>   1. If 'app-side-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

I've been trying on other pages and it works and it seems that it's not working only on the `app.component.ts`

app.component.html

```
    <ion-app>
      <ion-split-pane>
          <ion-menu>
              <ion-header>
                  <ion-toolbar>
                    <ion-title>
                      Menu
                    </ion-title>
                  </ion-toolbar>
                </ion-header>

                <ion-content>
                    <app-side-menu></app-side-menu>
                </ion-content>
          </ion-menu>
          <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>

      </ion-split-pane>
    </ion-app>
```

app.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SideMenuPageModule } from './side-menu/side-menu.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  exports : [
    SideMenuPageModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

side-menu.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { SideMenuPage } from './side-menu.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SideMenuPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [SideMenuPage]
})
export class SideMenuPageModule {}
```

Comment: Are you trying to render `SideMenuPage` in the router outlet or in the app.component.html template?  You have routing declared for `SideMenuPage` with path but you are also rending the element outside of the router outlet in `app.component.html`.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually displaying the side menu page outside the `router-outlet`
as @Jason White mentioned